# Can Weightlessness help cleaning lungs from Microorganism in Covid-19 patients?

Tags: covid-19, lungs

We know that cleaning lungs from Microorganisms in Covid-19 patients is hard. But In Weightlessness materials easily move around. So could Artificial Weightlessness help doctors for safer and more efficient cleaning lung from Microorganism?

Comment: This isn't medically plausible.

Comment: @Carey Gregory. I means creating Artificial Weightlessness in Operating theater. Not just in lung organ. rooms like those that astronauts practice in it.

Comment: There is no such thing as cleaning viruses from the lungs via surgical methods, the lungs aren't the only place the virus exists, and creating weightlessness is only possible in a space ship or a fairly powerful aircraft. There is simply nothing plausible about this idea at all.

Comment: You need to explain more about what you're thinking, it's difficult to visualise. Maybe link a reference? Until you update here I try to explain with whatever I understand from your question. If you are imagining microorganisms to be like sand particles that will start floating in the absence of gravity and can be collected easily and removed, you are wrong. Microorganisms are extremely light and exchange of gravitons(considering the theory of quantum gravity) is literally negligible. And there's much more than just gravity holding microorganisms inside.